# How to make center to EditText and Textview in android?

Tags: android, xml-layout

I'm new in Android. I've a problem with android design structure. I want to make TextView , EditText and Button at Center. But, I can't get it. Please help me. I want to develop like that picture.

[image]

Here my code sample.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:background="@color/isp_pin_maincolor"
          android:paddingTop="10dp"
          android:paddingBottom="10dp"
          android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    >
<TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="ISP"
        android:textColor="@color/isp_text"
        android:textSize="50dp"
        android:gravity="center"/>

<EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Enter PIN Code"
        android:id="@+id/editText" android:layout_gravity="center" android:numeric="integer"/>
<Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/pin_login"
        android:width="100dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/button"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

When I running, I got like that. [image]

That appears in top. Please help me for this. Thanks with advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this..

Remove this line `android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"` and add `android:gravity="center"` `android:layout_gravity="center"` for your main `LinearLayout`

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:background="@color/isp_pin_maincolor"
          android:paddingTop="10dp"
          android:paddingBottom="10dp"
          android:gravity="center"
          android:layout_gravity="center"
    >
```

Comment: Wow, that's incredible. I got it bro. Thanks for pointing to me.

Answer (score 2):

Replace this line `android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"` with `android:gravity="center"`

your code should be ..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:background="@color/isp_pin_maincolor"
      android:paddingTop="10dp"
      android:paddingBottom="10dp"
      android:gravity="center"
 >
<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="ISP"
    android:textColor="@color/isp_text"
    android:textSize="50dp"
    android:gravity="center"/>

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Enter PIN Code"
    android:id="@+id/editText" android:layout_gravity="center" android:numeric="integer"/>
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/pin_login"
    android:width="100dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/button"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:paddingTop="15dp"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:background="@color/isp_pin_maincolor"
          android:paddingBottom="10dp"
          android:gravity="center"
          android:layout_gravity="center">
```

try this You will be able to solve your problem.